# Login page is accepting all emails and passwords including those not stored in the database. No restricted acess at all

Tags: mysql, reactjs, node.js, forms, dom

I am working on a to-do app. I have already setup the signup and login page. Signup page is working perfectly as all details been inputed is already stored in the database(sql). The main challenge now the login page is accepting all emails and passwords including those not stored in the database there by allowing unrestricted access.

I have tried checking up on my server.js code but I couldn not really figure out what is wrong  also checked my api(post) request and I couldnt see what went wrong.I am using axios library.

```
    const handleSubmit=(event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setErrors(validation(values));
    if(errors.email=== "" && errors.password=== "") {
        axios.post('http://localhost:8081/login', values)
            .then(res => {
            if(res.data === "login successful") {
            navigate('/todo');
          } else { 
            alert("No record existed")
          }
          })
          .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }}



 app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
 const sql = "SELECT * FROM user_details WHERE `email`= ? AND 
 `password`= ?";
 db.query(sql, [req.body.email,req.body.password], (err, data) => {
    if(err) {
        return res.json(err);
    } else if(data) {
        return res.json("login successful");
       } else {
        return res.json("login failed");
         }
     })
     })

       app.listen(8081, () => {
       console.log("listening");
       })
```

Comment: Don´t store passwords as plain text in DB. Also, you are only checking if you have a response, not the response you get. Maybe your are getting an empty dataset in your `data` variable

Comment: Thanks @nacho it was an empty dataset issue. I have rectified it thanks I really appreciate your response. Cheers